# Why does background-colour doesn't fill the whole width on mobile device type althrough it has full width?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, google-chrome-devtools, bootstrap-5

I'am trying to build a responsive navbar using Bootstrap 5.3 and an additional CSS stylesteet.

I managed to arrange it quite good looking, but when I switch to mobile device type in Chrome dev-tools the backgound and the fonts beginn to scale when display width is smaller than 343 px.

It's a nice effect for the font, but not considering the background.

I found out that it does not happen in Firefox dev tools, so it is something Browser specific?

If you have other recommendations for my code to be more effective I would be happy to hear them.

Here is a link to my github repo:

https://github.com/jahokosan/coursera_Chinese-restaurant-side.git

And the parts of the code I suggest to be relevant.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>La Vang Chinese restaurent</title>
<!-- eigene styles.css erst NACH der bootstrap.css einbauen, damit mein code bei gleicher Spezifität überhand behält   -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

...

 </head>
  <body>

<!-- Navbar Grundgerüst; Hier die Farbe der Navbar festlegen -->
      <nav id="navbarcolor" class="navbar navbar-expand-md py-1">
        <div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Navbar Brand -->
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
              <div alt="Logo image" id="logoimg" class=" float-start d-none d-md-block">
              </div>
              <h1 id="restaurantname" class="navbar-brand pb-0">
              La Vang Chinese Bistro
              </h1>
        
              <p id="koshercertified">
                <img src="images/star-k-logo.png" alt="Kosher certification">
                <span class="navbar-text">Kosher Certified</span>
              </p>
          </a>
<!-- Button für die Navbar ab MD-Size -->
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#nimmalledatenvonHIER" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
<!-- Inhalte der Navbar, die bei MD-Size in den Toggler kommen  -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="nimmalledatenvonHIER">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">

...

styles CSS: 

.navbar-brand{
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        width: 200px
    } 
}
#navbarcolor{
    background-color: #f6b319;
    width: 100%
}
```

Thank you very much for your time and effort

First I tried to find out if some elements are "crashing" at the breakpoint where scalling happens, but I think that is not the case.

Then I tried to "play around" with some  css-settings in devtools by ticking off and on and I tried to apply the background not to the NAv element but to the inside container.

Then I found out that it does not happen in Firefox dev tools, so it is something Browser specific?

Comment: Thank you jahokosan for sharing your github link. Looking at the devtools for both chrome and firefox, the only odd thing that I saw was the green header text is wider than it's container when the viewport width was around 343px and lesser. Do you want the green header text to continue to sit within it's container? Or can you share what is the effect that you wish to achieve?

Comment: Looking back at the title of the post, I guess if you want to have the background of the heading to fill the whole width of the viewport of smaller (< 343px) size viewport, you can start by reducing the size of the font of this element for a start. <h1 id="restaurantname">

Comment: thank you very much for your reply @Jun Wen Soh . Indeed when I changed the h1 size to 5vw, so that it gets smaller with reduced viewport the background-colour of the navbar stays to full width until the screen is very small ( something about 210px). See here: https://github.com/jahokosan/coursera_Chinese-restaurant-side/tree/master/debugging I assume the background "shrinks" when the Viewport reaches the margin of h1 element, but I don't understand why, because the navbar element where the background styling is applied should have full width (100%)